# Calculations with random variables

Tags: python, math, random

I often need to do calculations such as the following:

> - A, B, C, D are independent random variables distributed uniformly in [0,1].
> - X := A+B and Y:=B+C+D.
> - What is the probability that X < Y?
> - What is the expected value of Y, given that Y < 2?
> - etc...

I thought that it might be possible with Python scipy, since it has a random-variable class. But, I did not find e.g. how to create a random-variable that is the sum of two given random-variables, or the conditional distribution of another variable. Is this possible in scipy, or in another library?

<sub>Note: I [asked a similar question in math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959638/29780), with no replies so far.</sub>

Comment: This indeed seems a math question rather than a coding question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: It is a question about how to program something in python / scipy...

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done with the random module. Printstatement: "What is the probability that X < Y?", What is the expected value of Y, given that Y < 2?"

```
import random
count = 0
for x in range(1000000):
    numbers = [random.random() for x in range(4)] 
    if (numbers[0] + numbers[1]) < (sum(numbers) - numbers[0]):
        count += 1
print float(count)/1000000, float(count)/1000000*2
```

Comment: This would be an estimation, not a calculation, but perhaps that is what the OP meant.